# UITableviewcell delete button apprearing when I swipe right to left on a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableview and I dont need to edit or delete the cells. So requirement is just view only. But when I swipe on a cell a red delete button appears. Please help how can I disable it.

Comment: You should take some time to read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" as well as read the reference docs for `UITableView`, `UITableViewDataSource`, and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options depending on your needs. If you don't need any cell editing of any kind then simply add this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Editing defaults to `YES` so you need to turn it off.

IF you need some editing but no deletion then implement:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Also, if you don't need either insert or delete, remove the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method that may have been added automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following method to your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: No, this will not work. If this method isn't implemented, it defaults to `YES` and the default editing mode for a row is `Delete`. And FYI - this is a data source method, not a delegate method.